# Is it a good practice to package jar and config for all environments (dev uat prod) in one zip?

Tags: java, deployment, environment

I am writing software deployed on unix servers by some operations team. The software is deployed to different environments by ops. Namely dev, uat and prod.

The executable will be configured differently on each environment thus env specific config files.

I need the process to be as simple as possible, as well as limiting the potential for human errors (simplicity definitely has a big impact on the latter).

One major advantage of the approach described in the title and reflected belowis that the deployment run book is environment independent. And the runbook is therefore ultra simple :

Login to the target deployment machine
Curl the zip file 
Unzip it
Run the executable with config wanted (dev, uat or prod)

Example of my current zip :

```
Executable jar file
App-dev.properties
App-uat.properties
App-prod.properties
```

I'm checking my options and looking for recommendations on best practices to make deployment as simple as possible and yet minimizing human error impact.

Comment: What config? What environment. Some more detail might lead to much better answers.

Comment: Unless you expand on your question *a lot*, I don't see how it can be reasonably answered. You cannot ask such a general question with no context at all and then expect a useful answer. [StackOverflow is not a mind-reader...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/153998)

Comment: Oh, and what is "uat" in your title? I can *guess* what "dev" and "prod" are (I am hoping that "prod" is not something to use with cattle, though) but "uat" eludes me...

Comment: UAT == User Acceptance Testing.

Comment: @StephenC: Interesting! I can honestly say I have never encountered the initials before - possibly because every time I had to fill in a related form for a project, those forms were as verbose and filled with legalese as possible...

Comment: @thkala - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_acceptance_testing#User_acceptance_testing for an example of the use of this abbreviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that good practice / bad practice come into it.  If it works for you, do it.

I presume that the real reason you are asking is to find out if there are any possible drawbacks.  The only ones I can think of are:

- If the configs include passwords or secret keys, then having an omnibus ZIP file in non-production machines is potentially exposing the production keys/passwords more than they need to be.
- This will result in more "versions" of the ZIP existing which might result in more issues with tracking them.  (Probably not though ... as there should be ways to deal with this.)
- (From thkala's comment) If you include the production configs in the ZIP file used on other platforms, there is a risk that someone might accidentally deploy a "production" system on a non-production platform.  That could potentially have disastrous consequences; e.g. trashed production databases or security issues.

Comment: There is also the issue of making sure that the final user won't end up installing one of the other configurations - that can be potentially very embarrassing, depending on the differences between the versions...